# Web accessibility - description for image button - outdated solution?

Tags: html, button, accessibility, wai-aria

I got some kind of accessibility test (for blind, deaf users, etc.) of a customer website and there are also hints how to improve the accesibility.

One of the hints is for image buttons:

> Additionally, the buttons should get a short and meaningful description, e.g. with an invisible text. The invisible    text    should    not be 
>   marked    with    the    attributes display:none and visibility:hidden. 
>   Instead the text should be moved out of the viewport:

```
<a href=”...”>[Font-Icon] <span class=“invisible“>Delete</span></a>
.invisible { position:absolute;  left:-10000px;  overflow:hidden;}
```

I'd like to ask if this is still reccomended solution. It seems outdated to me. Should I use some kind of `aria` tag instead of invisible  element, or is the suggested solution OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the buttons should get a short and meaningful description, e.g. with an invisible text.*
>
> It seems outdated to me.

You're right, this is not a solution.

When talking about accessibility we do not have to only focus on blind people using a screenreader but on all kind of disabilities. Moving a text out of viewport is a total nonsense. This used to be a *(bad)* solution for a small part of the population using screenreaders when ARIA was not supported, but this is no longer a real solution.

The best solution is still obviously to write the full text :

```
<a href="...">[Font-Icon] Delete</a>
```

Yes, obvious, but it deserves to be said.

The second solution is to use the `title` attribute. Why using it if it's not supported by screenreaders? Because 99% of the population do not use a screenreader. And the "[Font-Icon]" deserves to have an alternative. *(For better accessibility support, this `title` attribute should have a way to be visible on keyboard focus.)*

```
<a href="..." title="Delete">[Font-Icon]</a>
```

The final solution is to add the `aria-label` for screenreader users leaving the `title` attributes for other people.

```
<a href="..." title="Delete" aria-label="Delete">[Font-Icon]</a>
```